# How to sort a CSV column in powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to take a specific CSV column and sort it in ascending order but for some reason, the values I get are all messed up. For example, if column 1 of my csv file is 3,5,1,6,3, I want it to output in ascending order of 1,3,3,5,6.

This is what I am trying: (I also tried without the -property)

```
$csvFile = Import-CSV <mypath>
$sortColumn = $csvFile.column1 | Sort-Object -Property {$_ -as [decimal]}
```

Is there any quick way to do this? Perhaps is there a way to turn that column into an array and then sort it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your approach *should* work, assuming you're referencing the correct column, it won't be *quick*.

For a faster alternative, consider this:

```
# Simulate import of a CSV file.
$csvFile = @'
Num
3
5
1
6
3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# Convert the column values to an array of [decimal]s by way of a cast.
$nums = [decimal[]] $csvFile.Num

# Sort the array in place.
[Array]::Sort($nums)

# The above is the conceptual equivalent of the following, which is much slower:
# $nums = $csvFile.Num | Sort-Object { $_ -as [decimal] }
```

Outputting the sorted array `$nums` then yields:

```
1
3
3
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$_.yourcolumnname
```

rather than

```
$_
```

Comment: Note that the input in the question is `$csvFile.column1`, i.e., the values of a specific column. As such, the code in the question should work as-is, assuming that the `.column1` values can be converted to `[decimal]` - though it won't perform well.